# Adding parentheses to object declaration causes constructor not to run

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

Say I have an extremely simple Foo class like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() {std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;}
};
```

I have always thought that both `Foo foo` and `Foo foo()` would output `bar`, as they both call the constructor. But when I try:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing gets outputted. Is there a reason for this? How can I make sure that the constructor gets called in both instances?

[Ideone test](http://ideone.com/oaC5Aq)

Comment: This line `Foo foo()` is a function declaration, it does not construct a `Foo` object.

Comment: @splrs I fixed it, the code in the question I wrote from the editor without testing it, instead of copying it from the code I was compiling